# Python. Askopenfilename

Tags: python, tkinter, файлы

Можно ли, вызывая **"askopenfilename"**, спрятать некоторые файлы?

К примеру, в папке находятся файлы с расширением *".jpg"* и *".png"*, но пользователь должен видеть лишь *".png"*.

Answer (score 3):

Да. Как-то [так фильтры ставятся вроде](http://tkinter.unpythonic.net/wiki/tkFileDialog):

```
tkFileDialog.askopenfilename(defaultextension='.jpg',
                  filetypes=[('All files','*.*'), 
                             ('PNG pictures','*.png'), 
                             ('JPEG pictures','*.jpg')])
```

Comment: Спасибо за совет,  пофиксил. Просто очень давно в последний раз использовал Python и вообще мало писал на нем.

Answer (score 1):

Можно использовать `filetypes` параметр, чтобы показывать только избранные файлы как [упомянул @igumnov](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/416664/23044).

Вот самодостаточный пример для Питона 2 & 3, который печатает имя файла, выбранного пользователем, причём первоначально только png-файлы показаны:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
try:
    from Tkinter import Tk
    from tkFileDialog import askopenfilename
except ImportError: # Python 3
    from tkinter import Tk
    from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename

root = Tk()
root.withdraw() # hide the window
filename = askopenfilename(
    parent=root,
    title='Images',
    initialdir=os.path.expanduser(u'~/Pictures'),
    filetypes=[('PNG images', '.png'), ('JPEG images', '.jpg')])
root.destroy()
print(filename)
```